# Three monitor setup in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xrandr, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad E531 running Ubuntu 20. I want to connect two external monitors using the VGA and HDMI connectors on the notebook.

The problem that I am running into is that xrandr won't display more than one external monitor. For more it says:

> xrandr: Configure crtc 2 failed

I have tried using the ubuntu displays setting. Tried using xrandr and arandr. I tried setting one monitor after the other. I tried different settings with xrandr.

The best I got was the two external monitors mirroring and extending the laptop screen. Can anyone point me in the direction of the solution.

The output os `xrandr --listproviders` is:

```
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x48 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 6 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting

xrandr:

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 2130, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1050 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.95  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a cross-site question. Wrapping it up:

Use a dock (docking station), then install the latest [DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu) for your Ubuntu version *20.04*.

Cross-site journey:

- [Any really decent way to get three monitors? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1450377/1110856)
- [How to get three displays on Linux Mint 21 - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/731871/how-to-get-three-displays-on-linux-mint-21?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Ubuntu 21.04 with three external monitors - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1350597/1110856)